# Internacionalização em Java

Tags: java, layout, internacionalização

Estou tendo certas dificuldade para realizar a internacionalização da minha aplicação java.

A minha duvida é a seguinte: quando eu tenho uma tela de "login",por exemplo, e seleciona a opção no meu JMenuItem: "inglês", toda a minha aplicação, os meus layout, deveriam mudar conforme a opção selecionada, deixando ela toda em inglês.  Gostaria de saber como fazer para isso acontecer.

Segue o meu código de como estou fazendo estou tentando fazer:

Comment: Aos _downvoters_: faz bem comentar alternativas para melhorar a questão.

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação? É feito em swing? Se sim, você precisa alterar todos os textos manualmente em um método a parte.

Comment: E uma aplicação desktop e ela e feita com swing, vou alterar e posto aqui como ficou o meu código.

Comment: Por favor, poste um código que seja [mcve], para quq seja possivel reproduzi-lo e testa-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Então, você pode fazer isso utilizando um arquivo de linguagem. Seria algo do tipo:

1- Método para recuperar o arquivo de linguagem selecionado com base na opção de linguagem selecionada no JMenuItem (arquivos .lang estariam na pasta lang do projeto):

```
class Language {
private Properties language;
public void loadLanguage(int lang) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    if (lang == 0)
        language = getLanguageProperties("lang/english.lang");
    else if (lang == 1)
        language = getLanguageProperties("lang/portuguese.lang");
}

protected Properties getLanguageProperties(String languageFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File(languageFile);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file));
    return props;
}
}
```

2- Recuperar o texto de um componente através da sua chave:

```
class LanguageController {
    public static String getProperty(String key) {
       return language.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

3- Carregar texto dos componentes swing da aplicação:

```
JButton componente = new JButton();
componente.setText(
            LanguageController.getProperty(
                    "BOTAO_KEY")
```

4- O arquivo de linguagem conteria o conteúdo com a chave e valor ("portuguese.lang"):

```
BOTAO_KEY=Texto do meu button
```

Se tiver curiosidade, dá uma olhada no projeto em que eu fiz esse tratamento de internacionalização: https://sourceforge.net/projects/j-syncker/. Lá tem um menu de linguagem que permite o usuário trocar o idioma em tempo de execução. Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Por curiosidade, poderia mostrar isso aplicado na prática num exemplo simples?

Comment: Pronto, seria o item 3 que tem o exemplo. Ele carrega o texto do jbutton com base no idioma selecionado por padrão. Se o usuário quiser trocar o idioma, é só chamar o método loadLanguage.

Comment: E como isso vai ser salvo no arquivo?

Comment: Pronto, adicionei agora! Vlw pela dica :P