# Como posso internacionalizar o texto dentro do meu JOptionPane

Tags: java, internacionalização

Eu consegui internacionalizar a maioria do meu código, porém não consigo alterar o `JOptionpane` do botão AlterarEmpresa

Meu código esta assim no momento.

```
package Empresa;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import ConexaoBanco.EmpresaDAO;
import Entidades.Empresa;
import Usuario.IniciadorAtendente;
import Usuario.IniciadorFuncionario;

public class AlterarEmpresaAtendente extends JFrame {

    private ResourceBundle bn = null;

    public AlterarEmpresaAtendente()
    {
        setTitle("Alterar Empresa - Atendente");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JLabel lBusca = new JLabel("Buscar");
        JTextField tBusca = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lNome = new JLabel("Nome");
        JTextField tNome = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lCnpj = new JLabel("CNPJ");
        JTextField tCnpj = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lRazaoSocial = new JLabel("Razao Social");
        JTextField tRazaoSocial = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lConjunto = new JLabel("Conjuto");
        JTextField tConjunto = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lFuncionalidade = new JLabel("Funcionalidade");
        JLabel lHorarioAbertura = new JLabel("Horario Abetura");
        JTextField tHorarioAbertura = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lTemperaturaMin = new JLabel("Temperatura Min");
        JTextField tTemperaturaMin = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lHorarioDeEncerramento = new JLabel("Horario Encerramento");
        JTextField tHorarioDeEncerramento = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lTemperaturaMax = new JLabel("Temperatura Max");
        JTextField tTemperaturaMax = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lHorarioLigado = new JLabel("Horario Ar Ligado");
        JTextField tHorarioLigado = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lHorarioDesligado = new JLabel("Horario Ar Desligado");
        JTextField tHorarioDesligado = new JTextField(10);
        JButton bAlterar = new JButton("Alterar");
        JButton bLimpar = new JButton("Limpar");
        JButton bCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem espanhol = new JMenuItem("ESP");
        menu.add(espanhol);
        JMenuItem ingles = new JMenuItem("USA");
        menu.add(ingles);
        JMenuItem portugues = new JMenuItem("Portugues");
        menu.add(portugues);
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        bar.add(menu);

        c.add(lBusca);
        c.add(tBusca);
        c.add(lNome);
        c.add(tNome);
        c.add(lCnpj);
        c.add(tCnpj);
        c.add(lRazaoSocial);
        c.add(tRazaoSocial);
        c.add(lConjunto);
        c.add(tConjunto);
        c.add(lFuncionalidade);
        c.add(lHorarioAbertura);
        c.add(tHorarioAbertura);
        c.add(lTemperaturaMin);
        c.add(tTemperaturaMin);
        c.add(lHorarioDeEncerramento);
        c.add(tHorarioDeEncerramento);
        c.add(lTemperaturaMax);
        c.add(tTemperaturaMax);
        c.add(lHorarioLigado);
        c.add(tHorarioLigado);
        c.add(lHorarioDesligado);
        c.add(tHorarioDesligado);
        c.add(bAlterar);
        c.add(bLimpar);
        c.add(bCancelar);

        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);



        bAlterar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {


                Empresa empresa = new Empresa(); 
                empresa.setNomeEmpresa(tNome.getText());
                empresa.setCNPJ(tCnpj.getText());
                empresa.setRazaoSocial(tRazaoSocial.getText());
                empresa.setConjuntoNR(Integer.parseInt(tConjunto.getText()));
                empresa.setHorarioEntrada(tHorarioAbertura.getText());
                empresa.setHorarioEncerramento(tHorarioDeEncerramento.getText());
                empresa.setTemperaturaMin(Integer.parseInt(tTemperaturaMin.getText()));
                empresa.setTemperaturaMax(Integer.parseInt(tTemperaturaMax.getText()));
                empresa.setArLigar(tHorarioLigado.getText());
                empresa.setArDesligar(tHorarioDesligado.getText());
                EmpresaDAO empresad = new EmpresaDAO(); 
                try {
                    empresad.altera(empresa , tBusca.getText());
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empresa "+tNome.getText()+" foi alterada com sucesso !! ");

            }
        });

        bCancelar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
                new IniciadorAtendente();
                dispose();
            }
        });

        portugues.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
                bn = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ex2", new Locale("ex2", "ex2"));
                ingles.setText(bn.getString("USA"));
                espanhol.setText(bn.getString("ESP"));
                portugues.setText(bn.getString("Portugues"));
                setTitle(bn.getString("AlterarEmpresa"));

                lNome.setText(bn.getString("Nome"));

                lRazaoSocial.setText(bn.getString("RazaoSocial"));

                lConjunto.setText(bn.getString("Conjunto"));

                lFuncionalidade.setText(bn.getString("Funcionalidade"));

                lHorarioAbertura.setText(bn.getString("HorarioAbertura"));

                lTemperaturaMin.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMin"));

                lHorarioDeEncerramento.setText(bn.getString("HorarioEncerramento"));

                lTemperaturaMax.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMax"));

                lHorarioLigado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArLigado"));

                lHorarioDesligado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArDesligado"));

                bAlterar.setText(bn.getString("Alterar"));

                bLimpar.setText(bn.getString("Limpar"));

                bCancelar.setText(bn.getString("Cancelar"));

            }
        });

        ingles.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
                bn = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ex", new Locale("ex", "ex"));
                ingles.setText(bn.getString("USA"));

                espanhol.setText(bn.getString("ESP"));
                portugues.setText(bn.getString("Portugues"));

                setTitle(bn.getString("AlterarEmpresa"));

                lNome.setText(bn.getString("Nome"));

                lRazaoSocial.setText(bn.getString("RazaoSocial"));

                lConjunto.setText(bn.getString("Conjunto"));

                lFuncionalidade.setText(bn.getString("Funcionalidade"));

                lHorarioAbertura.setText(bn.getString("HorarioAbertura"));

                lTemperaturaMin.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMin"));

                lHorarioDeEncerramento.setText(bn.getString("HorarioEncerramento"));

                lTemperaturaMax.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMax"));

                lHorarioLigado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArLigado"));

                lHorarioDesligado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArDesligado"));

                bAlterar.setText(bn.getString("Alterar"));

                bLimpar.setText(bn.getString("Limpar"));

                bCancelar.setText(bn.getString("Cancelar"));

            }
        });

        espanhol.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
                bn = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ex1", new Locale("ex1", "ex1"));
                ingles.setText(bn.getString("USA"));
                portugues.setText(bn.getString("Portugues"));

                espanhol.setText(bn.getString("ESP"));

                setTitle(bn.getString("AlterarEmpresa"));

                lNome.setText(bn.getString("Nome"));

                lRazaoSocial.setText(bn.getString("RazaoSocial"));

                lConjunto.setText(bn.getString("Conjunto"));

                lFuncionalidade.setText(bn.getString("Funcionalidade"));

                lHorarioAbertura.setText(bn.getString("HorarioAbertura"));

                lTemperaturaMin.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMin"));

                lHorarioDeEncerramento.setText(bn.getString("HorarioEncerramento"));

                lTemperaturaMax.setText(bn.getString("TemperaturaMax"));

                lHorarioLigado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArLigado"));

                lHorarioDesligado.setText(bn.getString("HorarioArDesligado"));

                bAlterar.setText(bn.getString("Alterar"));

                bLimpar.setText(bn.getString("Limpar"));

                bCancelar.setText(bn.getString("Cancelar"));
                bn = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ex1", new Locale("ex1", "ex1"));
                ingles.setText(bn.getString("USA"));

                espanhol.setText(bn.getString("ESP"));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Veja esta pergunta: [Internacionalização em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150623/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-java/150626#150626)